# how to identify my skype status from my desktop wpf application

Tags: skype

Im building a WPF application which shows customized reminder in installed desktops, here i needs to verify my skype (skype for business) status in c# wpf code, if the skype status is in **"Do not disturb"** i will not show any reminder.

Can anyone help me out

Comment: There is no more  Skype API, Microsoft killed it. The only perverted way one can imagine is to somehow process web-interface page for your account.

Comment: Hi Ravi, my answer will depend on whether you are writing a win32 app or a modern Windows Store app.  I wrote the Lync 2013 SDK which you would use if you were creating a win32 desktop client in wpf or windows forms.

Comment: The "Skype API" referred to by Swift is actually the Lync 2013 API. It isn't dead and is supported on the win32 version of the desktop app.